# Disable Buttons in different tab

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, user-controls

have an application with 2 tabs which are A and B. Both of the tab has 2 buttons. Besides out of the tab got 1 OK button. (refer to screenshot)

[image]

How to implement

when I click Tab A Button 1 or 2, buttons in Tab B and OK will be disabled.
When click OK button, Tab A or B buttons will be disable.
If click on Tab B Button 1 or 2, Tab A and Ok button will be disable.
*(disable around 5-10sec, then will buttons will enable back)

no using prism framework and etc.

Main Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfGlobalCommand.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfGlobalCommand"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab A">
            <local:TabA DataContext="{Binding _TabAViewModel}" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab B">
            <local:TabB  DataContext="{Binding _TabBViewModel}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Button Main" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10" Command="{Binding _MainButton}" IsEnabled="{Binding _IsAvailable}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Main Window View Model C#

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _TabAButton1;
    private ICommand _TabAButton2;
    private ICommand _TabBButton1;
    private ICommand _TabBButton2;

    private TabAViewModel _tabAViewModel;

    public TabAViewModel _TabAViewModel
    {
        get { return _tabAViewModel; }
        set { _tabAViewModel = value; }
    }

    private TabBViewModel _tabBViewModel;

    public TabBViewModel _TabBViewModel
    {
        get { return _tabBViewModel; }
        set { _tabBViewModel = value; }
    }

    private ICommand _mainButton;

    public ICommand _MainButton
    {
        get { return _mainButton; }
        set { _mainButton = value; }
    }

    private bool _isAvailable = true;

    public bool _IsAvailable
    {
        get { return _isAvailable; }
        set { _isAvailable = value; OnPropertyChanged("_IsAvailable"); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _TabAButton1 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabAButton1Message));
        _TabAButton2 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabAButton2Message));
        _TabBButton1 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabBButton1Message));
        _TabBButton2 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabBButton2Message));
        _MainButton = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMainButtonMessage));

        _TabAViewModel = new TabAViewModel()
        {
            _TabAButton1 = this._TabAButton1,
            _TabAButton2 = this._TabAButton1,
        };

        _TabBViewModel = new TabBViewModel()
        {
            _TabBButton1 = this._TabBButton1,
            _TabBButton2 = this._TabBButton1,
        };

        DisableButtons(true);
    }

    private void ShowMainButtonMessage(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Main Button Message.");
    }

    private async void DisplayTabAButton1Message(object obj)
    {
        DisableButtons(false);
        MessageBox.Show("Tab A Button 1.");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        DisableButtons(true);
    }

    private async void DisplayTabAButton2Message(object obj)
    {
        DisableButtons(false);
        MessageBox.Show("Tab A Button 2.");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        DisableButtons(true);
    }

    private async void DisplayTabBButton1Message(object obj)
    {
        DisableButtons(false);
        MessageBox.Show("Tab B Button 2.");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        DisableButtons(true);
    }

    private async void DisplayTabBButton2Message(object obj)
    {
        DisableButtons(false);
        MessageBox.Show("Tab B Button 1.");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        DisableButtons(true);
    }

    private void DisableButtons(bool value)
    {
        _tabAViewModel._IsAvailable = value;
        _tabBViewModel._IsAvailable = value;
        _IsAvailable = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

Tab A XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfGlobalCommand.TabA"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10" />
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Button A 1" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10" Command="{Binding _TabAButton1}" IsEnabled="{Binding _IsAvailable}" />
        <Button Content="Button A 2" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10" Command="{Binding _TabAButton2}" IsEnabled="{Binding _IsAvailable}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Tab A View Model C#

```
 public class TabAViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _tabAButton1;

    public ICommand _TabAButton1
    {
        get { return _tabAButton1; }
        set { _tabAButton1 = value; }
    }

    private ICommand _tabAButton2;

    public ICommand _TabAButton2
    {
        get { return _tabAButton2; }
        set { _tabAButton2 = value; }
    }

    private bool _isAvailable;

    public bool _IsAvailable
    {
        get { return _isAvailable; }
        set { _isAvailable = value; OnPropertyChanged("_IsAvailable"); }
    }

    public TabAViewModel()
    {
        //_TabAButton1 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabAButton1Message));
        //_TabAButton2 = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(DisplayTabAButton2Message));
    }

    //private void DisplayTabAButton1Message(object obj)
    //{
    //    MessageBox.Show("Tab A Button 1.");
    //}

    //private async void DisplayTabAButton2Message(object obj)
    //{
    //    //_IsAvailable = false;
    //    MessageBox.Show("Tab A Button 2.");
    //    await Task.Delay(5000);
    //    //_IsAvailable = true;
    //}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
}
```

I have done a sample but are there anyways to improve the strcture or apply design pattern ?
Thanks

Comment: Cannot you disable while tab instead of buttons inside?

Comment: @Maximus hi, currently I focusing on develop a new module same behaviour as previous system. But your suggestion will consider and discuss with my boss. Because as you can see my MainViewModel very heavy because all the implementation at there.

Comment: @Maximus If disable tab must be both, when button being click in either tab A / B